# List of Replica Symmetry results for different models?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, probability

Does anyone know of a good source that might have a list of problems or models along with what kind of replica symmetry they are conjectured to have?

I am aware of some of the more famous results, e.g. Sherrington-Kirkpatrick spin glass model and the spherical model being FRSB (Full Replica Symmetry Breaking) and random K-SAT being 1-RSB, but I am wondering if there is some kind of compendium somewhere of these kinds of results/conjectures.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: ...In other words, give the full meaning of SK, FRSB, K-SAT, 1-RSB.